# GPU Memory Allocation under CUDA 8 and Pascal Architecture

Tags: cuda, gpu

Pascal Architecture has brought an amazing feature for CUDA developers by upgrading the unified memory behavior, allowing them to allocate GPU memory way bigger than available on the system.

I am just curious about how this is implemented under the hood. I have tested it out by "cudaMallocManaging" a huge buffer and `nvidia-smi` isn't showing anything (unless the buffer size is under the available GDDR).

Comment: Demand paging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just curious about how this is implemented under the hood. I have tested it out by "cudaMallocManaging" a huge buffer and nvidia-smi isn't showing anything (unless the buffer size is under the available GDDR).

First of all I suggest you do [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all CUDA API calls.  It would seem from your description that you are not.

demand-paging in unified memory (UM) allowing the increase in memory size beyond the GPU physical DRAM memory will only work with:

1. Pascal (or future) GPUs
2. CUDA 8 (or future) toolkit

Other than that, your setup should probably work.  If it's not working for you with CUDA 8 (not CUDA 8RC) and a Pascal GPU, make sure that you meet the requirements (e.g. OS) for UM and also do proper error checking.  Rather than trying to infer what is happening from `nvidia-smi`, run an actual test on the allocated memory.

For a more general description of the feature I refer you to [this blog article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-8-features-revealed/).